# parsing a pdf to get the text between address and date

Tags: regex, ruby, parsing, pdf

I want to get some information(Rel type) from parsing pdf. Now the problem is text is stuck sometime between the address and a date. Im attaching the picture of the pdf page [image: Example of a pdf page]. When I parse the page I got the following text.

```
 Court Order -  01/30/2023    400 Block HANLON WAY\n                                                                                             Own\n                                                                                             Recognizance\n\n
```

How to get the **rel_type = Court Order - Own Recognizance** I have tried this regex but its only gives me full rel type where it's not broken into many lines

```
rel_typesmacthes = total_page.scan(/([MF])\s+(\d{2})\s+(\d{3})\s+([A-Z]{3}|t Specif t Spee)?\s+([A-Z]{3}|t Specif| t Spee)?\s+(.+)?(\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{2}\s+\d{1,2}:\d{2}\s+(?:am|pm))\s+(.+)?\s+(?:(\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/2023))?/)
```

this is the page. inspect looks like

```
                Name                                       BookDate Time                DateOfBirth              Booking #            Bail Amount

                    MARK,DEONTAE                                   1/28/23 9:40 am               02/25/1998              CC23NM711        $0 Race          Gen    Height   Weight    Hair  Eyes     Job Description    Arrest Date Time   Rel type       Release Date Arrest Location

BLACK           M      72       159     BLK    BRO                     1/28/23 8:26 am                                 800 Block VAQUEROS AVE RODEO   Arrest Type

     On View

        Charge                                     Charge Description
              148(A)(1) PC                         OBSTRUCT/ETC PUB OFCR/ETC

        Charge                                     Charge Description

              273.6(A) PC                          VIO ORD:PREVNT DOMES VIOL   Arrest Type

     Parole Hold

        Charge                                     Charge Description

              3000.08 PC                           VIOLATION OF PAROLE
        Charge                                     Charge Description

              AB109                                AB109 REALIGNMENT

                        Name                                       BookDate Time                DateOfBirth              Booking #        Bail Amount
                MENDOZA-FREGOZA,LIDIO                              1/28/23 3:25 pm               10/20/1989              CC23NM719        $0

Race          Gen    Height   Weight    Hair  Eyes     Job Description Arrest Date Time   Rel type       Release Date Arrest Location HISPANIC        M      67       175     BLK    BRO                     1/28/23 2:42 pm    Court Order -  01/30/2023    400 Block HANLON WAY
                                                                                             Own
                                                                                             Recognizance

  Arrest Type
     Bench Warrant

        Charge                                     Charge Description

              10851(A) VC                          VEHICLE THEFT

        Charge                                     Charge Description
              466 PC                               POSSESS BURGLARY TOOLS

        Charge                                     Charge Description

              496D(A) PC                           POSS STOLEN VEH/VES/ETC

        Charge                                     Charge Description
              594(A) PC                            VANDALISM

        Charge                                     Charge Description

              978.5 PC                             BENCH WARRANT:FTA:FELONY
```

Comment: PDFs would spread the your example over multiple lines. Your code needs to handle multiple lines.

Comment: and how to get the rel type ?

Comment: In general pdf is a graphical format. Plus sometimes a pile of letters and their positions. Its main goals are to look consistent and print reliably. Providing a parseable format that follows the logical structure of the data is not a priority. What other options do you have?

Comment: Show the `page.text.inspect` output if we need to help you with the details. You should be able to determine the column start and stop offsets by looking for the position of `rel_type`. For the next lines get the text within the column.

Comment: I suggest that you read this: [Why not upload images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/12149471)?

Comment: @Gerhard please check the page.inspect

Answer (score 0):

From your data I got:

```
s = ["Race          Gen    Height   Weight    Hair  Eyes     Job Description Arrest Date Time   Rel type       Release Date Arrest Location HISPANIC        M      67       175     BLK    BRO                     1/28/23 2:42 pm    Court Order -  01/30/2023    400 Block HANLON WAY",
     "                                                                                               Own",
     "                                                                                             Recognizance"]
```

To cleverly read the text from an pdf and parse it line for line in an array as the data shown above:

```
require 'pdf/reader'

reader = PDF::Reader.new(pdf_file_path)

reader.pages.each do |page|
  page.text.lines each do |line|
    # now you handling it as array, line by line
  end
end
```

Scanning line for line:

```
(start, stop) = s[0].scan(/Rel type/).map { [Regexp.last_match.begin(0), Regexp.last_match.end(0)] }[0]
```

Check if we found the next line with release type header:

```
if (start != nil)
```

Split the existing line and get the data text from the current(split line) and the following lines:

```
data = s[0].scan(/Rel type.*Arrest Location(.*)/)
puts data[0][0][90 .. 105].strip
puts s[1][start .. -1].strip
puts s[2][start .. -1].strip
```

Initially I thought of using start and stop to figure out if there is multiple columns of text. But the columns are fixed(in my experience of scraping PDFs) so the position in text should be the same for all lines and you can us a fixed offset. If not use start and stop.

Executing this code gives me:

```
Court Order -
Own
Recognizance
```

Comment: its not giving me ' Court Order - ' it should be ' Court Order - Own Recognizance ' Im only getting ' Own Recognizance'

Comment: I was going to accept your answer but you have so cleverly broken the string into 3 parts. Why is that? In parsing the pdf we get all of this as single string

Comment: If you are going to try handle it one page at a time you are going to have a hard time. It is much more cleverly to handle it a line at a time.

Comment: but I have almost 256 pages of pdf

Comment: That is why there are loops in ruby.